# Do I need cPanel like software for my Production Server?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu-16.04, alibaba-cloud

I recently created a Wordpress on a dedicated Linux instance on Alibaba Cloud ECS Instance. I previously have experience with shared hosting like GoDaddy, HostGator. As I set up everything on my own, my question here is

1. Do I need to have cPanel Like software installed on my Linux instance? Is there anything else I should look before I go design my complete site in full swing?

I am new to dedicated hosting, Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No, you don't. And if you use it anyway, your questions would become [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need any web hosting control panels. Welcome to The Light Side! Now you finally get to learn how to configure everything by yourself. You're on your path to professionalism and freedom.

1. Plan what kind of services you need.
2. Read through some tutorials; *how to set up X on [your Linux distribution]*.
3. Do the configuration with the modifications you need.
4. Come back to Serverfault when you have a problem despite following the tutorial and reading the manual.

Answer (score -3):

I think you need cPanel software. the ECS is just like an empty linux machine. you need install software by yourself. you want to save that time ,you would choose your serverless functions not ECS.